# DateTime UTC Horário de verâo NF-e

Tags: c#, datetime, nfe

Como é posso alterar o fuso horário de uma variável do tipo `DateTime`?

A ideia é fazer uma rotina onde o usuário não tenha necessidade de alterar a hora do computador para efetuar transmissões de NF-e, porém que seja dinâmico sem ter que chumbar no código o fuso horário atual.

Comment: Por favor, explique um pouco melhor o que deseja fazer. Talvez um pseudo-código ajude.

Comment: A NF- exite uma tag onde é necessário passar a data e hora no formato UTC (-03:00), lembrando que estamos no horário de verão ele altera esse fuso horário para (-02:00), fazendo com que a nota gere erros nos campos devido a essa diferença.
Em muitos casos alguns programadores preferem não alterar o horário do computador/servidor responsável por esse tipo de emissão, porém gostaria de uma solução mais dinâmica sem que dependa do usuáro

Comment: isso me parece POG

Comment: @RovannLinhalis qual seria sua solução, já que todo computador hoje atualiza a hora automáticamente no horário de verão e a receita mantem como padrão o horário em GMT(-03:00).
Lembrando que não posso enviar o horario com GMT(-02:00), pois recebo um retorno de tag incorreta.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb495915(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Tem alguma referência que a receita mantém GMT-0300 sempre? Não duvido porque governo faz dessas mesmo. O correto é usar *local time*, que trata horário de verão, ou UTC pra ficar agnóstico.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo o manual de orientação do contribuinte, a Sefaz adota sim o horário de verão. Sendo assim, você deve informar o fuso -03:00 quando não estiver no horário de verão e -02:00 quando estiver (considerando horário de Brasília).

Exemplo da tag `dhEvento` na página 81:

```
Data e hora do evento no formato AAAA-MMDDThh:mm:ssTZD
(UTC - Universal Coordinated
Time, onde TZD pode ser -02:00 (Fernando de
Noronha), -03:00 (Brasília) ou -04:00 (Manaus), no
horário de verão serão -01:00, -02:00 e -03:00. Ex.:
2010-08-19T13:00:15-03:00.
```

> Link do manual: http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/exibirArquivo.aspx?conteudo=URCYvjVMIzI=

Um problema que pode acontecer, é que, no windows há a opção `Ajustar automaticamente para o horário de verão`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> (Considere a hora de envio como agora, 14:00)

Caso essa opção não esteja marcada, e seu horário esteja correto, você irá enviar 14:00 no fuso -03:00 e a sefaz irá receber em 14:00 no fuso -02:00. Vai haver rejeição.

O correto é a opção estar marcada, e o envio será no fuso -02:00, mesmo que seu fuso esteja `(UTC-03:00) Brasília`.

Fiz alguns testes:

Fuso do windows (UTC-03:00) Brasília, opção desmarcada:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz"));
```

Resultado: `2017-11-08T14:05:55-03:00`

Fuso do windows (UTC-03:00) Brasília, opção marcada:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz"));
```

Resultado: `2017-11-08T14:03:34-02:00`